# UIButton scale on hover animation - iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiviewanimation

So I have a UIButton and I want it to scale larger when the user touches up inside, but scales back down if the user drags their finger away using UIView animations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your code what you does for that

Comment: I don't have any code for the animation yet

Comment: you need to increase size when your tap button on resize it when focus goes out from button, I am right?

Comment: Yea, when the user presses down it enlarges, if the users doesn't commit to press and drags finger away it goes back to the original size.

Comment: means on press it increases size and release decrease or come at initial size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UIControlEventTouchDown, you'd want to increase the size of the button, and then on UIControlEventTouchDragExit you'd want to decrease it again. You could do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)touchDown:(UIButton*)sender{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^{
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
    }];
}

-(IBAction)touchDragExit:(UIButton*)sender{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^{
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }];
}
```

Of course, you would probably also want to decrease the size of the button on touch up, touch cancel, etc.

Make sure to wire up the button to these methods, either in Interface Builder (as I was presuming in my example, hence the IBActions), or in code when you create the button:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDragExit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
```

Comment: touchDragExit method when called can you please explain it, I am confused it's not called at me. thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to add a target to the button for that event. Either wire it up with Interface Builder (as I was presuming in my example, hence the IBActions), or use [button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDragExit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit]. 
UIControlEventTouchDragExit is performed when the user presses a button, keeps their finger down, and moves their finger outside of the button's frame while still holding down.

Comment: yes i know that, but I am asking about when touchDragExit method called on which action, its not called here, please help I am little bit confused about it.

Comment: UIControlEventTouchDragExit is performed when the user presses the button, keeps their finger down, and moves their finger outside of the button's frame while still holding down. UIControlEventTouchUpOutside would then be performed if the user lifts their finger.

Comment: thanks Adrew I am following same thing but that touchDragExit method not called when I drag out side of button frame, may I can't fire that action on device. :(

Comment: Well I'm not sure what the problem is if you have the events wired up correctly. I just built a test project and touchDragExit functions correctly on an actual device (as well as in the simulator).

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)buttonScaleAnimation:(UIButton *)sender {
    float animationDuration = 0.25;
    // Increase scale to 1.25 with animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Return to original scale with animation
        [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }];
}
```